# How triggers behave wrt concurrent visibility of transactions?

Tags: postgresql, serialization, transactions, triggers, visibility

I'm working on PostgreSQL 8.4 in read committed mode.
I know that for each query, the server makes a snapshot of db state so that
the query behaves consistently.
Does it include triggers that are called in response to this query?
Or is there a new snapshot created for each query called from within a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers work in the same transaction as the outer query, it will see the same snapshot.

Comment: I know they are in the same transaction but the transaction is read committed. So i'm not so sure about the snapshot. Do you know if it's documented somewhere?

Comment: Read committed sees all information that is committed by other transactions. Also when this information is committed after your transaction has started, that's why it's called "read committed". Information inserted/updated/deleted inside your own transaction, is alwsay visible for your own transaction. See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html